# Label language, how to change to local names

Tags: language, wikibase

I'm viewing Wikidata with Swedish set as my user interface language. This turns all the language names in the list of labels into Swedish, which makes the list hard to follow in my opinion since the list is ordered by language code and not localised name. I would like the list to show local names instead of the translated ones, is there any way of doing this? Preferably I'd also like the list to also show the language code of the items.